# Working with change to 2 elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQ) {                   
  jQ('.WorkType').on("change", function(){
   if (jQ(this).val() == 'Standard Hours'){
    jQ(this).closest('.DayTimeWrapper').find('.Hours').addClass("Calc_Hours");
    jQ(this).closest('.DayTimeWrapper').find('.Hours').removeClass("Calc_Leave");
    jQ(this).closest('.DayTimeWrapper').find('.Hours').removeClass("Calc_RDO");
   }else if (jQ(this).val() == 'RDO'){
    jQ(this).closest('.DayTimeWrapper').find('.Hours').addClass("Calc_RDO");
    jQ(this).closest('.DayTimeWrapper').find('.Hours').removeClass("Calc_Leave");
    jQ(this).closest('.DayTimeWrapper').find('.Hours').removeClass("Calc_Hours");    
   }else{
    jQ(this).closest('.DayTimeWrapper').find('.Hours').addClass("Calc_Leave");
    jQ(this).closest('.DayTimeWrapper').find('.Hours').removeClass("Calc_RDO");
    jQ(this).closest('.DayTimeWrapper').find('.Hours').removeClass("Calc_Hours");
   }
   window.setTimeout(function () {
    jQ(".Calc_Hours").sum("focusout", "#standard_hours");
    jQ(".Calc_Leave").sum("focusout", "#leave_hours");
    jQ(".Calc_RDO").sum("focusout", "#rdo_hours");
    },1000);
  }) 
 })
```

This code traverses the dom on a change to the element with the class WorkType and modifies the class attributes of the Hours element situated within the div DayTimeWrapper. It then performs calculations and places the results to the elements with ID as specified.

It works perfectly

However i need to perform the same calculations on  additional elements with the class set to setTime so i modified the code as follows

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQ) {                   
  jQ('.WorkType,.setTime').on("change", function(){
   if (jQ('.DayTimeWrapper').closest('.WorkType').val() == 'Standard Hours'){
    jQ(this).closest('.DayTimeWrapper').find('.Hours').addClass("Calc_Hours");
    jQ(this).closest('.DayTimeWrapper').find('.Hours').removeClass("Calc_Leave");
    jQ(this).closest('.DayTimeWrapper').find('.Hours').removeClass("Calc_RDO");
   if (jQ('.DayTimeWrapper').closest('.WorkType').val() == 'RDO'){
    jQ(this).closest('.DayTimeWrapper').find('.Hours').addClass("Calc_RDO");
    jQ(this).closest('.DayTimeWrapper').find('.Hours').removeClass("Calc_Leave");
    jQ(this).closest('.DayTimeWrapper').find('.Hours').removeClass("Calc_Hours");    
   }else{
    jQ(this).closest('.DayTimeWrapper').find('.Hours').addClass("Calc_Leave");
    jQ(this).closest('.DayTimeWrapper').find('.Hours').removeClass("Calc_RDO");
    jQ(this).closest('.DayTimeWrapper').find('.Hours').removeClass("Calc_Hours");
   }
   window.setTimeout(function () {
    jQ(".Calc_Hours").sum("focusout", "#standard_hours");
    jQ(".Calc_Leave").sum("focusout", "#leave_hours");
    jQ(".Calc_RDO").sum("focusout", "#rdo_hours");
    },1000);
  }) 
 })
```

This is not working and i am at pains to figure out why. The error in the console is

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Any help to resolve this would be appreciated

Comment: Your first `if` statement is missing its closing bracket; it looks like you accidentally converted your `else if` into an `if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not close the bracket after the first `if` statement. I've optimized your selectors for performance & readability:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (jQ) {
    jQ('.WorkType,.setTime').on("change", function () {
        var $hours = jQ(this).closest('.DayTimeWrapper').find('.Hours');
        var workType = jQ('.DayTimeWrapper').closest('.WorkType').val();
        if (workType == 'Standard Hours') {
            $hours.addClass("Calc_Hours");
            $hours.removeClass("Calc_Leave");
            $hours.removeClass("Calc_RDO");
        } else if (workType == 'RDO') {
            $hours.addClass("Calc_RDO");
            $hours.removeClass("Calc_Leave");
            $hours.removeClass("Calc_Hours");
        } else {
            $hours.addClass("Calc_Leave");
            $hours.removeClass("Calc_RDO");
            $hours.removeClass("Calc_Hours");
        }

        // The following code seems to be corrupt:
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            jQ(".Calc_Hours").sum("focusout", "#standard_hours");
            jQ(".Calc_Leave").sum("focusout", "#leave_hours");
            jQ(".Calc_RDO").sum("focusout", "#rdo_hours");
        }, 1000);

    })
});
```

**Edit:**

This seems to be what you want to do:

https://jsfiddle.net/mk07fof5/1/

```
$('.WorkType,.setTime').on("change", function() {
    var $currRow = $(this).closest('.DayTimeWrapper'),
        $allRows = $currRow.closest('.DayTimeTable').find('.DayTimeWrapper');

    calculate($currRow); //pass the element which triggered the event

    var CalcHours = 0,
        MealHours = 0,
        RdoHours = 0;

    $allRows.each(function(i) {
        $row = $(this);
        var hours = ParseFloat($row.find('.Hours').val());
        if(!hours) return;
        var workType = $row.find('.WorkType').val();
        switch (workType) {
            case 'Standard Hours':
                CalcHours += hours;
                break;
            case 'RDO':
                RdoHours += hours;
                break;
            default:
                MealHours += hours;
        }
    });

    $("#standard_hours").html(CalcHours.toFixed(2));
    $("#leave_hours").html(MealHours.toFixed(2));
    $("#rdo_hours").html(RdoHours.toFixed(2));
});
```

Don't forget to wrap your table into this div:

```
<div class="DayTimeTable">[...]</div>
```

Comment: Actually I'm not sure about the structure of your HTML, but the selectors can still be optimized. I think you could use just one selector for the `.DayTimeWrapper` and even more.

Comment: The code you have posted does not alter the class attributes. It does not error but it does not work. The logic i am trying to capture is that if a user modifies an input box with the class set to setTime then check the value of the select box with a class of worktype and modify the class of the Hours input box based on that value. All this needs to be done within the containing div DayTimeWrapper (there are multiple instances of DayTimeWrapper). I also want the class attribute of Hours changed if the sected option within the WorkType select box is changed.

Comment: The selectors might not be traversing correctly. Please create a jsfiddle of your HTML form and link it in your question.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/byax2dqL   The idea is that if you enter legitimate values into the input boxes eg StartTime 08:30 FinishTime 17:00 MealStart 12:00 and MealFinish 12:30 this will calculate on change of FinishTime and MealFinish and place the value in hours. Once you select the Worktype, this will populate the appropriate section at the top of the form. This is controlled by the class that is dynamiccally assigned to Hours (calculations are also run)

Comment: Hi Fabian thanks for your update, sorry for the delay in getting back. I took your code and applied it to my page making a few changes to accomodate the html structure i have. Your code works when calculating hours and minutes if whole hours are entered but any times that result in a fraction of an hour, lets say 7.50 Hours calculates correctly on the line but the Grand Total rounds to the nearest hour. I have mucked around for the past couple of days but cant seem to get the totals to display correctly. Any Ideas (its the same for your fiddle)

Comment: OK - solution was simple, just changed ParseInt to ParseFloat for the variable "hours"